# AWS Lambda limit concurrency from Unreserved concurrency pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Suppose I have a lambda that I want to limit the max number of concurrent functions initialized to 10, but I'm okay if this max number needs to reduce to below 10 in cases where the Unreserved Concurrency Limit available during that time on the account is less than 10. Is that not possible?

From the documentation, it looks like if I set the Reserved Concurrency to 10, that will limit the max initializations to 10 but it **reduces that number** from the Unreserved Account Concurrency. Can I set a max limit without taking a hit on the Unreserved Concurrency Limit of the account?

I've also attached a snipped from the AWS Docs on Reserved Concurrency.

Thanks in Advance.

From [Lambda function scaling - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-concurrency.html):

> **Reserved concurrency**
> If you want to guarantee that a certain amount of concurrency is available for your function at any time, use reserved concurrency.
>
> Reserved concurrency is the maximum number of concurrent instances you want to allocate to your function. When you dedicate reserved concurrency to a function, no other function can use that concurrency. In other words, setting reserved concurrency can impact the concurrency pool that's available to other functions. Functions that don't have reserved concurrency share the remaining pool of unreserved concurrency.
>
> Configuring reserved concurrency counts towards your overall account concurrency limit. There is no charge for configuring reserved concurrency for a function.

Comment: No, there is no way but why do you care? As the docs say: reserving concurrency incurs no cost. If you get low on unreserved concurrency just create a limit increase support request.

Comment: If you are worried about consuming concurrency, you can always ask AWS for an increase to the default limit of 1000 concurrent executions.

Comment: Does requesting for increase in the limit of concurrent executions incur extra cost?

Comment: Obviously not, no.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reserve Lambda concurrency without reducing the unreserved concurrency, but the unreserved concurrency can be easily increased with a support request, which you can open directly from the Service Quotas page: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/lambda/quotas/L-B99A9384